# I turn to the string array, which does not exist apparent in arrays.xml

Tags: android, fragment, translation

I am new to android development and I'm trying to develop an application but I experience a crash.

Here's my `strings.xml`, which also contains some `string-arrays` - when I try to get one of the arrays (see below) my app crashes.

```
<string-array name="Insurance_type">
        <item>Comprehensive</item>
        <item>Required</item>
    </string-array>

       <string-array name="Private">
        <item>@string/Abarth</item>
        <item>@string/Audi</item>
     </string-array>

    <string-array name="Audi">
        <item>@string/A1</item>
        <item>@string/A3</item>
        <item>@string/New_A3</item>
        <item>@string/A4</item>
        <item>@string/A5</item>
        <item>@string/S1</item>
        <item>@string/Audi80</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="A3">
        <item>TFSI(1197)Automat Attraction 105hp</item>
        <item>TFSI(1197)Automat Sharp 105hp</item>
        <item>TFSI(1390)Automat Limiter 3 Doors</item>
        <item>TFSI(1390)Automat Limiter 5 Doors</item>
        <item>TFSI(1390)Automat Sharp 3 Doors</item>
        <item>Automat(1595)3 Dors Attraction</item>
        <item>Automat(1781)3 Dors Ambiente</item>
        <item>Automat(1595)5 Dors New shape Attraction</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="A3serial">
        <item>19190</item>
        <item>19191</item>
        <item>19192</item>
        <item>a19192</item>
        <item>19193</item>
        <item>19195</item>
        <item>19196</item>
    </string-array>
```

**Here's the relevant code that triggers the crash:**

```
case R.id.btnSubModel:
        id =res.getIdentifier(chosenModel, "array", getActivity().getPackageName());
        data[0] = res.getStringArray(id);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data[0]);
        dialog.setTitle("Select Sub-Model");
```

**This is the stack trace of the exception I get:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: shuka_ins.co.il.shukainsuranceproject, PID: 2414
        android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x0
                at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:502)
                at shuka_ins.co.il.shukainsuranceproject.CarFragment.onClick(CarFragment.java:199)
                at shuka_ins.co.il.shukainsuranceproject.CarFragment$3.onItemClick(CarFragment.java:189)
                at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
                at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
                at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
```

Comment: Looks like `id` has the wrong value, I think you need to look into what that's getting set to.

Comment: It has neither crashed, but only after I used @string/

Comment: I assume you mean it's working if you don't use `getIdentifier`.  Presumably you're using @array and not @string, but anyway that doesn't surprise me because `getIdentifier` was not giving you the right value.  That's where the original problem is.